# ubuntu 16.04 install snapd problem

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-installation, dpkg, snap

Having problem with installing/uninstalling snapd.

My version of snap on my Ubuntu 16.04 for some reason is not correct:

```
snap --version
 snap    2.31.1~14.04
 snapd   unavailable
 series  -
```

So I want to reinstall the snad manually using:

```
sudo apt-get install snapd
```

and get the error:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/snapd_2.33.1~14.04_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I decided to uninstall this version by trying to use this command:

```
sudo apt purge snapd ubuntu-core-launcher squashfs-tools
```

giving me this result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'ubuntu-core-launcher' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  snapd* squashfs-tools*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 79,3 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 312065 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing snapd (2.31.1~14.04) ...
Failed to stop snapd.autoimport.service: Unit snapd.autoimport.service not loaded.
Failed to stop snapd.socket: Unit snapd.socket not loaded.
Failed to stop snapd.service: Unit snapd.service not loaded.
dpkg: error processing package snapd (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
dpkg: squashfs-tools: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 snapd depends on squashfs-tools; however:
  Package squashfs-tools is to be removed.

Removing squashfs-tools (1:4.3-3ubuntu2.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 snapd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

Command:

```
apt-get -f install
```

won't help as well.

```
~$ apt-cache policy snapd

snapd:
  Installed: 2.31.1~14.04
  Candidate: 2.33.1~14.04
  Version table:
     2.33.1~14.04 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-proposed/universe amd64 Packages
     2.32.9 500
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.32.9~14.04 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
 *** 2.31.1~14.04 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.0.2 500
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Please, if you get any idea of what's going on and how to fix this help me :)

Edit:

Trusty packages that I have in a souces list:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: I would check your sources (what have you added there, and do you have trusty (14.04) sources?) - you should be getting 2.39.9 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=snapd) and not have a trusty (14.04) version.  Can you add `apt-cache policy snapd` to your question.

Comment: @guiverc, I added information that you asked to my question.

Comment: I would comment out your 'trusty' sources; I can't see what they can provide you extra (with a tiny change of complications) unless you know of a reason to use them. I comment them out (put a # at start of line in /etc/apt/sources.list for those lines) as its easy to put them back if you need to reverse it (I also leave a "#- lines marked this way were commented out 2018-06-28 guiverc" (ie. doco explaining why) which I also do when I add sources (so I can remember why). Once command out; you can `sudo apt update` then try again.

Comment: The trusty version (2.33) was given priority as it's a higher number than the correct xenial version (2.32.9) as 2.33>2.32.9 according to `apt`'s logic. Removing the 'trusty' sources should fix...  (*don't forget to `sudo apt-get update` first*)

Comment: @guiverc well i'll tried to remove the souse, and now i see that ubuntu is trying to install the correct verions of file but still have an error due instalation `Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/snapd_2.32.9_amd64.deb`

Comment: Like the prior one, I'd do a `apt-cache policy snapd` to see where it's coming from  (no need to post it here). all versions of Ubuntu should be the same (except trusty & cosmic) [https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=snapd].  I'd try `sudo apt -f install` again, maybe `sudo apt install  --reinstall snapd` (I'd be somewhat guided by what I saw in `apt-cache policy` output)... *let me know if problem persists; I'm heading to bed :)*

Comment: enable xenial-proposed, update sources & see if snapd will upgrade. If that happens to work install and or open synaptic > Origins. See if there are any other trusty packages installed. If so replace with xenial, in either case then remove the trusty repos from your sources. It was not a good or in any way useful idea to have them.

Comment: Thanks you for answers @doug, @guiverc, I finnaly get the point of my problem,    the last step is to clean the `var/lib/dpkg/info` from all that concerns snap like this `sudo rm ./snapd*` and then `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and finish with `sudo apt install --reinstall snapd` and that's to the god of linux get the output of the `snap --version` command like: `snap    2.32.9
snapd   2.32.9
series  16
ubuntu  16.04
kernel  4.4.0-130-generic`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My version of resolving this issue:

1. Remove/comment all unnessesary trusty sources from your
   `/etc/apt/sources.list`.
2. Run `sudo apt-get update` and verify
   that `apt-cache policy snapd` is now have the `Candidate: 2.32.9`
   that you need. try to `sudo apt install --reinstall snapd`.
3. Optional. If you still have `Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an
   error code (1)` error, clean the `cd var/lib/dpkg/info` with `sudo
   rm ./snapd*` and reinstall the snapd `sudo apt install --reinstall
   snapd`.
4. Verify that the Installed version is 2.32.9 `snap
   --version`.