# Unable to uninstall snapd 2.34.2 in 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, snap

I've been having problems with upgrading snapd with apt-get. I've tried running `dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get install -f`, but the system hangs indefinitely setting up snapd. I've also read numerous posts on how to resolve this issue, but unfortunately none of them have worked. Some [posts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037431/receiving-the-error-snapd-snap-repair-service-is-a-disabled-or-a-static-unit-n?noredirect=1) seem [promising](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2328152), but my main problem is that I cannot uninnstall snapd because `the subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1.` Right before this error message, the system says the job for `snapd.service` and `snapd.socket` have been canceled. I have tried everything I know to try, and searched around the net, but would appreciate some insight from you all about this issue!

So far, I have tried: `sudo apt purge snapd` and `sudo apt purge snapd ubuntu-core-launcher squashfs-tools`, but I get the same results.

Comment: what version of Ubuntu is this?

Comment: Hi, I'm using version 16.04

Comment: Try this `sudo apt purge snapd ubuntu-core-launcher squashfs-tools` seen here https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2328152

Comment: I have indeed tried this! Same result

Comment: Stop it first with `sudo systemctl stop snapd` then disable `sudo systemctl disable snapd` then try to remove it!

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same result even after stopping and disabling snapd.

Comment: Lets try this. Please update and upgrade your system then try again for this is indeed a strange behaviour!

Comment: Right, updating works fine, but when I upgrade, it gets stuck on "setting up snapd", which is what caused this mess lol.

Comment: Please look at the methods here lets re-install then see if the upgrade will work https://askubuntu.com/a/1050466/459561

Comment: I'm working on reinstalling snapd, but I think your previous advice may have messed things up because when I do `sudo apt install --reinstall snapd`, I get: `Internal Error, No file name for snapd:amd64`

Comment: Start and enable it then try again!

Comment: I've enabled snapd, and tried to reinstall it, but there's `No file name for snapd:amd64` again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add more flesh to George's answer. I needed to

1. `cd /var/lib/dpkg/updates/`
2. `sudo rm *`
3. `sudo fuser -vki /var/lib/dpkg/lock (bc there was a lock on dpkg process)`
4. `sudo systemctl stop snapd (stop the snapd process..if it's running)`
5. `sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` (solves: `Internal Error  no file name for snapd:amd64`)
6. `sudo apt purge snapd ubuntu-core-launcher squashfs-tools`

I'm not sure if steps 1) and 2) are necessary, but at the end of the day, this is what worked for me. I'm not sure, but could my system still reinstall snapd when I do `sudo apt-get update/upgrade`?

Comment: Ok  that it finally worked, run that update and upgrade command and let us know!

Comment: update and upgrade works, no snapd problems!

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
sudo apt purge snapd ubuntu-core-launcher squashfs-tools
```

Found [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2328152).